# Google Apps script filename lookup failure

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that finds a file by (unique) filename:

```
function getFileByName(filename) {
  var files = DocsList.getRootFolder().find("title:" + '"' + filename + '"');    
  Logger.log("looking for " + filename);
  for( var i in files){
    Logger.log("checking " + files[i].getName());
    if ( files[i].getName() == filename ) 
    {
      Logger.log("found " + files[i].getName());
      return files[i];
    }
  } //for i in files    
  Logger.log("did not find " + filename);
} //getFileByName_
```

It worked like a charm for months, until yesterday. Now it doesn't seem like the loop is running (I added the `Logger.log("checking " + files[i].getName());` line to debug, but I never see that show up in the log.

Any ideas (or other ideas for debugging?)? Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of files.length?

Comment: Debug it step by step. Are you sure the file is in root and not in another subfolder? If not dont use getRootFolder and search directly in the entire drive o another folder.

Comment: files.length = 0. It's definitely in the root, exactly where it's been for the last three months. Is there a different func. that searches the whole drive, though? Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: When I read your question an then the answer I just don't see the link between both... did I misunderstood something or could you explain?

Comment: You said explicitly that your original code used to work for months , did it as it is?  Why then removing title solved the issue?

Comment: Yes - it worked as shown above. I don't know why removing title fixed it, though I'm glad that it did.

Comment: Well I'm happy for you (sincerely) but  nevertheless I think this thread remains confusing an I regret the answer doesn't provide any attempt to explain nor to understand... too bad for people reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "title" and look just for the file name live the code bellow.

```
function getFileByName(filename) {
var files = DocsList.getRootFolder().find(filename);    
Logger.log("looking for " + filename);
for( var i in files){
 Logger.log("checking " + files[i].getName());
if ( files[i].getName() == filename ) 
{
  Logger.log("found " + files[i].getName());
  return files[i];
}
} //for i in files    
Logger.log("did not find " + filename);
} //getFileByName_
```

Comment: This worked, but I had previously tried `var file = DocsList.getRootFolder().find("Reassessment Requesttemp");`, which is the value that I'm passing to it. Any idea why they don't give the same behavior?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't undersdant what you tried. Can you explain a litle bit more?

Comment: @DeltaG- Can I ask why you were searching 'title:filename'  instead of simply the filename in the first place?  What is the idea behind your choice?

Comment: @braraujo: the value of filename is always "Reassessment Requesttemp". I tried `var file = DocsList.getRootFolder().find("Reassessment Requesttemp");` also, but it didn't work. It seems to me that they should be equivalent.

Comment: @Sergeinsas: When I originally put together the code, that was what it took to work. It was my understanding that the `.find()` method searched for a string in the contents by default, whereas I was looking for a file by name. I got the approach from somewhere else on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the information,I commented above. Also, I agree it should have worked as you think.